# Naming a XLSX file

Tags: xlsxwriter

I want to generate XLSX file and save it with custom name, for instance, "current time" or a series of names like hello[i] 0

```
def excel_print(self):
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('walk1.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet.write(0,4, time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) ))
        worksheet.set_column(0, 0, 30)
        worksheet.write(0,0,"No of steps")
        worksheet.write(0,1,self.steps)
        workbook.close()
```

Now in the above code, each time I run the program,I want file to be saved with different name. Is that possible??

Comment: I suppose you can pass in variables to `xlsxwriter.Workbook()`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook(str(bookTitle)+".xlsx")` is the solution I have used in my code and it works.

You will just need to pass in the variable that I have named `bookTitle` in this case. If `bookTitle` is already a string you won't need the str at the front of `str(bookTitle)` however with your example `hello[i], (str(hello[i])+".xlsx")` should work.